# javax.swing.GroupLayout, не правильно распологаются компоненты

Tags: java, swing

Что я делаю не так, не правильно располагается `JLabel`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layoutMessage = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
setLayout(layoutMessage);

GroupLayout.ParallelGroup horizontal = layoutMessage.createParallelGroup(); //LE
GroupLayout.SequentialGroup horizontalPart = layoutMessage.createSequentialGroup();

GroupLayout.ParallelGroup vertical = layoutMessage.createParallelGroup(); //UP
GroupLayout.SequentialGroup verticalPart = layoutMessage.createSequentialGroup();

horizontal.addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, horizontalPart);
vertical.addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, verticalPart);

layoutMessage.setHorizontalGroup(horizontal);
layoutMessage.setVerticalGroup(vertical);

/////

JLabel test = new JLabel("TESTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");

horizontalPart.addGap(5);
verticalPart.addGap(2);

horizontalPart.addComponent(test);
verticalPart.addComponent(true, test);

JLabel test2 = new JLabel("5353");
horizontal.addComponent(test2);
verticalPart.addComponent(test2);

JLabel test3 = new JLabel("5353666");

horizontalPart.addComponent(test3);
vertical.addComponent(test3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Постарался сохранить ваш порядок в коде, но это скорее запутывает, чем помогает:

```
    GroupLayout.ParallelGroup horizontal = layoutMessage.createParallelGroup(); //LE (h1)
    GroupLayout.SequentialGroup horizontalPart = layoutMessage.createSequentialGroup();

    GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vertical = layoutMessage.createSequentialGroup(); // (v1)
    GroupLayout.ParallelGroup verticalPart = layoutMessage.createParallelGroup();

    layoutMessage.setHorizontalGroup(horizontal);
    layoutMessage.setVerticalGroup(vertical);

    /////

    JLabel test = new JLabel("TESTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
    test.setOpaque( true ); test.setBackground( Color.YELLOW );
    JLabel test2 = new JLabel("5353");
    test2.setOpaque( true ); test2.setBackground( Color.GREEN );
    JLabel test3 = new JLabel("5353666");
    test3.setOpaque( true ); test3.setBackground( Color.ORANGE );

    horizontalPart.addGap(5);
    verticalPart.addGap(2);

    horizontal.addComponent(test); //(h2)
    horizontal.addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, horizontalPart); //(h3)

    vertical.addComponent( test ); //(v1.1)
    vertical.addGroup( verticalPart ); //(v1.2)

    horizontalPart.addComponent(test2); //(h3.1)
    verticalPart.addComponent(test2); //(v2)

    horizontalPart.addComponent(test3); //(h3.2)
    verticalPart.addComponent(test3); //(v3)
```

Схема расположения по горизонтали:

[image: Горизонтальная группировка]

- `ParallelGroup` (h1):

  - `test` (h2)
  - `SequentialGroup` (h3):

    - `test2` (h3.1)
    - `test3` (h3.2)

Схема расположения по вертикали:

[image: Вертикальная группировка]

- `SequentialGroup` (v1):

  - `test` (v1.1)
  - `ParallelGroup` (v1.2):

    - `test2` (v2)
    - `test3` (v3)

Comment: Да спасибо, но оказывается я немного не так писал кодик, ваще не так) проще писать код так как генит сама студия в древовидной форме.